# JSF performance varies for the same view after subsequent calls

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

I have set-up a view with a backing bean that loads all of it's data on startup. 
All methods are constant time and I have added timers to check that they behave consistently. I have a ServletRequestListener that measures the entry/exit time.

**Problem**: Once I load the page I have some Ajax links that render parts of the page (without changing the state of my ViewScope bean). These calls take from 90 millis to 600 millis and the time is reducing as I click on my ajax link. Can someone point where should I direct my investigations? Could this be due to View serialization at random times or maybe re-compilation of the view?

Using JSF2, Tomcat 7 with Mojarra 2.1.19

web.xml extract

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.developmentMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.compressViewState</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: You shouldn't make performance tests with `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` set to `Development`

Comment: You are right. I forgot to remove it when I pasted. The behaviour is exactly the same.